# Glitch in simple three.js animation

Tags: animation, three.js, rendering, visual-glitch

I am noticing a tiny glitch in a very simple animation using three.js. You have to look closely but it's there. It is just a cube that goes from left to right recursively. Here is the render loop :

```
var then = Date.now();
var direction = 1;

function render() {

  mesh.position.x += direction * 0.1 * (Date.now() - then);

  then = Date.now();

  // put boundaries in animation
  if (mesh.position.x > 140) {
    direction = -1;
    mesh.position.x = 140;
  }
  if (mesh.position.x < -140) {
    direction = 1;
    mesh.position.x = -140;
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

Here is an example :

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, geometry, material, mesh;

init();


function init() {

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 400;
  scene.add(camera);

  geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200);
  material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();

}

var then = Date.now();
var direction = 1;

function render() {

  mesh.position.x += direction * 0.1 * (Date.now() - then);
  then = Date.now();
  if (mesh.position.x > 140) {
    direction = -1;
    mesh.position.x = 140;
  }
  if (mesh.position.x < -140) {
    direction = 1;
    mesh.position.x = -140;
  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r54/three.min.js"></script>
```

I tried in different browsers (chrome and firefox) and different PCs and it's there.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I just ran it (Win10 Home, i7, Intel Iris GPU, 16GB memory), and it ran smoothly for me. Are you seeing the jitter as specific times, or does it appear randomly?

Comment: @TheJim01 it seems that it appears every X seconds but I am not sure. Even here http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/requestanimationframe.shtml the cube animation is jittering a bit (scroll down to see the cube). You think it might be my laptop's problem?

Comment: `CanvasRenderer` and r54. What about `WebGLRenderer` and r85?

Comment: @prisoner849 you are right but here is the same example with r82 and WebGLRenderer : https://jsfiddle.net/Thanos_Sar/sm6p9e5q/1/ . You see the tiny jitters in this too right?

Comment: I've noticed it there just once. During of popping up of an advert banner of jsfiddle.net in the left bottom corner in the page.

Comment: @prisoner849 after the popping you don't ever notice it?

Comment: Correct. As I said, it happened just one time.

Comment: Trying again today, I did see one stutter, but @prisoner849 is right, it only happens when that ad comes into the jsfiddle page. This is because everything is running in the main thread, including the UI. (You aren't going to get around this for now.) Perhaps you have other plugins and things occupying some processor cycles? Try launching in incognito/private mode (extensions disabled) and see if that helps.

Comment: @TheJim01 I have tried in 2 different laptops, in 3 different browsers. It is happening in all of them. And it is the simplest animation three.js can do. It is very strange. I have made many animations with three.js before and it's the first time I notice this. The stutter seems to be periodic on my laptop too.

Comment: Just to add to the observations: Your SO snippet runs flawless for me (Win10 desktop). The jsfiddle jitters once or twice during add loading.

Comment: @Paul-Jan thanks. It is so weird, I am trying to blame my GPU or browser for this but it happens in other laptop and browser too.

Comment: This may sound like a dumb question, but have you tried running this outside jsfiddle? To me is seems like jsfiddle is the problem, and you're getting hung up on its deficiency. If it still jitters on a stand-alone HTML page, then it's definitely something specific to your test system(s). Try adding `Stats.js` (it's used on all the three.js example pages) and see if the stats record an FPS drop when you're noticing the jitter.

Comment: @TheJim01 Yes I have tried it outside jsfiddle. Basically I created the jsfiddle after detecting the problem inside an app I am developing. After some logging I saw that requestAnimationFrame was not called normally. It was called for 15 times with a "similar" time interval and suddenly it was called for the 16th time after a much more big time interval (appr. x3 of the median of the previous). What could cause this?

Comment: Good debugging there. Not sure what would cause it. You said you've tried on different browsers on different machines. Do these machines all have the same hardware specs? Are they all within the same organization? And a gut guess: Do they all run the same antivirus with some form of browser protection?

Comment: @TheJim01 they are both Asus Laptops but with different specs and very different price. No custom antivirus on neither, only what win10 have. So you think a desktop app could affect a web app rendering process?

Comment: What else is left? Browser versions, though you're probably using the latest without even realizing it. (FYI Chrome = 59, Firefox = 53) It's unlikely, but if an errant process is somehow briefly spiking your CPU, it could cause performance issues for all other apps. If you could find a pattern in when your animation loop runs long, you may be able to correlate it to another application that's occasionally hitting 100% CPU.